# Why am I getting an error when connecting to a MySQL Database

Tags: python, mysql

I cannot seem to figure out why I'm getting this error. Any ideas?

I have double-checked the username and password. I'm using A2 Hosting to host my MySQL database.

```
(.venv) lukebouch@MacBook-Pro-2 20200815-BiblicalResponses % "/Users/lukebouch/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Development/Projects/20200815-BiblicalResponses/.venv/bin/python" "/Users/lukebouch/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Development/Projects/20200815-BiblicalResponses/util/database.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lukebouch/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Development/Projects/20200815-BiblicalResponses/util/database.py", line 3, in <module>
    db = mysql.connector.connect(
  File "/Users/lukebouch/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Development/Projects/20200815-BiblicalResponses/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/lukebouch/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Development/Projects/20200815-BiblicalResponses/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/lukebouch/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Development/Projects/20200815-BiblicalResponses/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 716, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/Users/lukebouch/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Development/Projects/20200815-BiblicalResponses/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 208, in _open_connection
    self._do_auth(self._user, self._password,
  File "/Users/lukebouch/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Development/Projects/20200815-BiblicalResponses/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 144, in _do_auth
    self._auth_switch_request(username, password)
  File "/Users/lukebouch/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Development/Projects/20200815-BiblicalResponses/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 177, in _auth_switch_request
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'lukesmed_biblical'@'c-73-31-227-71.hsd1.va.comcast.net' (using password: YES)
```

Here is my code. Obviously, I have excluded the username and password.

```
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="",
  user="",
  password="",
  database="",
)
print(db)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `password` parameter should be spelled out correctly (`password` not `passwd`).

You are also missing a couple of parameters.

Here is the correct syntax:

```
db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="",
    user="",
    password="",
    database="",
)
```

Comment: Oh! That is what I saw on an article I read. I thought it looked strange! Thanks so much!

Comment: Try specifying a database

Comment: Sorry for the noob question but how do I do that?

Comment: just like you specify a host, user, etc. under password say `database="NAME_OF_DATABASE"`

Comment: The python syntax of what I posted works for me. At this point the issue may be in external factors, such as, wrong username, wrong password, incorrectly setup config file, etc. Use this article to try and solve the external issue: https://vispud.blogspot.com/2019/01/accessing-mysql-from-python-3-access.html

Comment: Just figured it out! I had not setup a remote for the database. Thanks